# Can't access directories after setting rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess

I can't access directories on my host/server, after setting htaccess rewrite rules.
The rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-a0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

it's supposed to internally redirect `http://domianname.com/index.php?page=login` to `http://domianname.com/login`

but now i can't access directories on my server like `http://domianname.com/admin`.
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need rewrite conditions to skip files/directories from rewriting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-a0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```